# How to add a library from the system folders to an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, hidden-files

For example, glfw for Max OS installed the library in /usr/local/lib/.  Now I want to use it in an Xcode project. I can't seem to add it because Mac Finder has hidden that folder.

How do I find it to add? Ideally how do I just paste in an arbitary path somewhere without having to drag files from Finder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really isn't a programming question to do with glfw. It's more to do with "how do I open hidden or system folders ...". [This is answered here.](https://superuser.com/questions/44086/open-folder-for-a-given-path-in-mac-os-x)

For Xcode specifically, you could right-click an appropriate group folder and click Add>Existing Frameworks... then click Add Other, then use the Cmd-Shift-G shortcut to get the "Go to this folder:" in the open panel (standard in all open/save panels). Choose your library and you're off.

Comment: That did it thanks, I would never have figured out the magic key combo